# Wrapping Room's @insert into RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, repository-pattern, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to use RxJava2 with Room persistence library and it is working well for @Query annotation in DAO file but for @Insert it is saying that it will not return anything from RxJava2 so how do I wrap it in Observable to use with RxJava2.

DAO file

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {
@Insert
void insert(Word word);

@Query("delete from word_table")
void deleteAll();
@Query("select * from word_table order by word_id asc limit 1")
Maybe<Word> getTheIndexOfTopWord();
}
```

Repository file from where I'm calling these functions,

```
public class Repository {

private WordDao wordDao;
private WordRoomDatabase db;

private LiveData<List<Word>> allWords;

public Repository(Application application) {
    db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    wordDao = db.wordDao();
    allWords = wordDao.getAllWords();
}

public LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
    return allWords;
}

public void insertWord(Word word) {
//here I can't subscribe due to the return type-----------------------
    db.wordDao().insert(word).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new MaybeObserver<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: Use `Completable`.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define your `insert()` method as below.

```
@Insert
long insert(Word word);
```

where the `long` value returned is the id of your `Word` entity. (You can return whatever datatype matches your `Word` entity's id)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do it is

```
@Dao
public interface SomeDao{
 @Insert
 long[] insert(Word word);
}
```

and in Rxjava is

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> yourDataBase.someDao().insert(word)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();
```

Insert should always return long[], or Long[]. you cannot wrap it in observable. But you can still wrap it in callable of either single, observable or flowable.

Comment: depends on the requirement

Comment: The right way depends on the use case. If you are not concerned about if the data is inserted into the database you can choose Completable otherwise If I am returning long from it I would be needing Single. @LordRaydenMK